# 403 Forbidden error for getting drives for shareddrive mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to send a request for a shared mailbox user: GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/drive](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserId%7D/drive)
This shared mailbox user doesn't have an OneDrive setup.
Expected result: 404 error with Error Code: ResourceNotFound.
Actual Result: 403 Forbidden with Error Code: UknownError and empty Message

For other entities, like email, calendar I got 200 with the same user.
I would like to know if it can be fixed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. As you said, you should get 404 when user has no OneDrive setup - I get that here. Could you show the whole error from MS Graph with the response details? And is the drive in question OneDrive for business?

Comment: Do you have permission? Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Here full stack trace: ```com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: UnknownError
Error message: 

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myUser/drive
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.2
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


403 : Forbidden```

Comment: I believe I have permissions because for other entries I got 200 for this user.

Comment: Perhaps the account is "frozen", you need to go into it through the browser and unfreeze.